# boost:bind and two methods with the same name and args count

Tags: c++, boost

I have a class with two methods

```
bool Syntax::removeTarget( CommandParam &params );
```

and

```
bool Syntax::removeTarget( const std::string & targetId );
```

How can I bind the second method? `boost::bind(&Syntax::removeTarget, this, _1)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disambiguate overloads, you have to cast (or otherwise coerce) them to the proper type. This should work:

```
boost::bind(static_cast<bool (Syntax::*)(const std::string&)>(&Syntax::removeTarget), this, _1);
```